# "Error: 21211 The 'To' number is not a valid phone number" with Twilio using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

the following image is my frontend design:

[image]

This is my Node.js script:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const twilio = require('twilio');

const accountSid = 'ACf230d111a9b9e90dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const authToken = '3ed072e00862729axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const app = express();

app.use(cors());  // blocks browser from restricting any data

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the Express Server')
})

app.get('/send-text', (req, res) => {
    // GET variables, passed via query string
    const { recipient, textmessage } = req.query;
    console.log(req.query);

    // Send text
    client.messages.create({
        body: textmessage,
        to: '+1' + recipient,
        from: '+15593134060'
    }).then((message) => console.log(message.body)).catch(e => { console.error('Got an error:', e.code, e.message); });
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Running on Port 4000"));
```

I put 'x' on a part of the Twilio sid and token on here for security purposes.

I expect that when I press the `Send Text` button, I would expect to send the message to myself because I use the same numbers for both "from" and "to".

However, I got the following error instead:

[image]

I think the format is correct, but I don't know why Twilio is telling me the number is invalid. I test with my friend's phone number and the result is the same. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Please note that I just sign up for the Twilio account and just copy and paste the Sid and token, I have not done any configuration. Also, the number I used here is my actual phone number, not Twilio number. I have tested on my phone that I can message myself and see the message.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Twilio's error code page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21211#possible-causes) You attempted to send a message or place a call from a Twilio number to itself. You have to use **to** parameter as the destination number, and the **from** parameter must be a Twilio phone number that you own.
[More info](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages)

Comment: The +15593134060 number that you see is not a twilio number. It's actually my personal phone number. I think either the "from" or "to" number has to be a twilio number. It cannot both be real number not from Twilio.

Comment: Do you know how to make it so that I can have the user send a message with his number and go through the Twilio API, then Twilio will deliver the message to my number on my phone?

Comment: Comment updated, you could take a look at the documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is the fact that you placed a call from a twilio number to the same twilio number. If you don't do that, I.E. use another number as the receiver of the message, your code should work.

Comment: The +15593134060 number that you see is not a twilio number. It's actually my personal phone number.

Comment: I think either the "from" or "to" number has to be a Twilio number. It cannot both be real number not from Twilio.

Comment: Do you know how to make it so that I can have the user send a message with his number and go through the Twilio API, then Twilio will deliver the message to my number on my phone?

Comment: I am not sure, but I will for sure look into it.